# GFCI Receptacles not resetting

Tags: electrical

I don't  know much about electricity.

In my kitchen there are 3 GFCI receptacles. There was a kettle plugged into one and the microwave. The fridge was on the other.  Both outlets quit last night when I opened the fridge, but the breaker didn't trip.

The reset buttons won't do anything, the green light at the bottom of the receptacle is off (on these GFCIs the light is on when they have power).

Every other outlet on this circuit is working, including the other GFCIs.

Any ideas what happened here?

Should I replace the GFCI outlets?

Comment: Were you using the microwave and/or kettle at the time? Did you press the reset button in far enough? Are you sure that the dead GFCIs are on the same circuit as the other receptacles? It's not clear from the question exactly what was plugged in where, and which GFCIs won't reset. Can you clarify? What size is the breaker that's  feeding the receptacle?

Comment: If it will not reset that is a classic symptom if it not receiving power.  Start tracing from the breaker box to make sure it isn't a bad breaker.  If it is the wiring you will want professional assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try unplugging your appliances and see if you can get the GFCIs to reset.

From there, if you can't get them to reset, possibly one of them is defective.

If the GFCIs do reset, possibly one of the appliances is broken.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried unplugging the appliances and the GFI would not reset. I guess I'll try replacing to see if they're defective.